# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.dll ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

This issue is making me crazy from past two days and I couldn't find any recursion is happening on this method and this issue happening recently, though none of the code has been changed, the following is my code

Calling the procedure:

```
Dim dssw As New Data.DataSet
dssw = RepSWSC()
```

The procedure:

```
Public Function RepSWSC() As Data.DataSet
    Dim strConn As String = GetConnString()
    Dim patient As String = String.Empty
    Dim qid As String = String.Empty

    patient = Session("patient")
    qid = Session("qid")
    Dim con As SqlConnection

    If con Is Nothing Then
        con = New SqlConnection(strConn)
    End If

    Try
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("spTestCall", con)
        command.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Dim parameter As SqlParameter = command.Parameters.Add("@house_id", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        parameter.Value = patient
        parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@q_id", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        parameter.Value = qid

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()
        End If

        con.Open()
        Dim theDataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        Dim ds As Data.DataSet = New Data.DataSet()
        theDataAdapter.Fill(ds)
        con.Close()

        Return ds
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        con = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Stack Trace

```
BusinessAccessLayer.dll!BusinessAccessLayer.TestClass.RepSWSC() Line 17971 + 0xe bytes  Basic
BusinessAccessLayer.dll!BusinessAccessLayer.TestClass.PopulateAnestRecordPDF(System.Data.DataRow dr, ceTe.DynamicPDF.Merger.MergeDocument objMergeDocument, String pdflabelname, Short BMI1, Short repanestcommentsdir, String CopyLabel, Boolean isRideHome, Boolean isNurseAssess, Boolean combineIDandDOS, Boolean allowoneproconly, Boolean showchiefc, Boolean showsurg, Boolean showsurglabel, Boolean specialTulane, Boolean showcmsinfo, Boolean checkCMSHotline, Boolean showEndo, Boolean showKGLB, Boolean trimaddallergies, Boolean showprecautions, Boolean showDiagTesting, Boolean trimAnestComp, Boolean HCALabel, String PageString, Boolean showMRN, Boolean alwaysShowChiefC, Boolean ridenameonly, Boolean showCultural, Boolean indentProcedure, Boolean showDOBSeparate, Boolean incDOSLabel, Boolean showPCP, Boolean NameLstFst, Boolean MergeAllergy, Boolean MidWestNursing, Boolean LastDoseLineForMeds, Boolean splitsurghist, Boolean PrinAnneSpecial, Boolean showMRNLabel, Boolean showCMSLabel, Boolean MergePsychtoNeuro, Boolean XNegHx, Boolean ShowSpecialists, Boolean XHaveMeds, Boolean TrimAllergies, Boolean expandWNL, Boolean xLatex, Boolean xHCP, Boolean showLang, Boolean NoMeds, Boolean NoAllergies, Boolean incEENT, Boolean ridephoneonly, Boolean LakelandAssess, Boolean indentTobacco, Boolean indentETOH, Boolean indentDrugs, Boolean flowallergies, Boolean showphones, Boolean xNoSurgs, Boolean xNoAnestComp, Boolean IncComboAlg, Boolean IncNameField, Boolean showmedlist, Boolean MakeAllergyList, Boolean showAMMeds, Boolean showReligion, Boolean showLongMSPONV, Boolean NoShowDx, Boolean showAgeonPatLab, Boolean showPatPhone, Boolean LatexUppercase, Boolean LakelandNoReactions, Boolean MGHBWSpecial, Boolean incDOBLabel, Boolean incDRLabel, Boolean isJerseyShoreNurse, Boolean showHCPno, Boolean showOtherLangX, Boolean checkPatLegalAge, Boolean isCommonwealth, Boolean MelbourneAlgIndent, Boolean MelbourneAnestCompIndent, Boolean combineIDDOSplus, Boolean NarrativeSurgeries, Boolean showPrimLangandSpkEng, Boolean RideRelationshipOnly, Boolean isMelbourneNurse, Boolean showAdvDir, Boolean showLeaveMsg, Boolean UseCondensedRideHome, Boolean showAdvDirX, Boolean showAnestCompBreakout, Boolean showMRSA, Boolean showHCPtext, Boolean showDocNameLastFirst, Boolean showSimpleLang, Boolean FlowMeds, Boolean isMtVernonEndo, Boolean showStaffUpdateName, Boolean showSpecialistsSeparated, Boolean showPCPSeparated, Boolean SNMSCIndent, Boolean showCaregiver, Boolean showSimpleProc, Boolean showBlackstoneAlg, Boolean showDentalBreakOut, Boolean showDOSmeds, Boolean showAge, Boolean indentProcedureMore, Boolean incSex, Boolean smallIndCombMedAlg, Boolean isSouthwest, Boolean DocContactAuth, Boolean isNSMCPhysical, Boolean showHCPName, Boolean showAdvDirName, Boolean isNorthPointe, Boolean isHSCC, Boolean MergeAnest, Boolean trimComboAllergies, Boolean isStLucie, Boolean isMasonRidge, Boolean showDiagTestingCombined, Boolean showInfDisease, Boolean isSWSC, Boolean MergeSubstance, Boolean isSummitView, Boolean showSummitViewInfections, Boolean TrimComboAlg, Boolean showPatAddress, Boolean showPatEmail, Boolean showPedsBMI, Boolean isOSE, Boolean showDOSSeparate, Boolean isMEE, Boolean showHosAddress, Boolean indentRoS, Boolean showCulturalX, Boolean showHxFalls, Boolean showSafety, Boolean showADHCPCombo, Boolean showFoodAllergy, Boolean showNonLabelDOBSeparate, Boolean showDiagTestingCombinedLineBreaks, Boolean SurgeryPerformedatFac, Boolean showBSA, Boolean ShowGreensboroAddAllergy, Boolean showFoodEnvironmentAlg, Boolean isUMAss, Boolean showNotifyPerson, Boolean isLosRoblesMC, Boolean isLakeside, Boolean isStJohns, Boolean showmalighyperX, Boolean isMusculoSC, Boolean AnestCompOneLine, Boolean showWarnings, Boolean showDentureX, Boolean showContactGlassX, Boolean isOSESurgeryPain, Boolean showExpSplitSurgList, Boolean showSTOPBANGScore, Boolean showOnlySurgPerfAtFac, Boolean ShowMedDoseFreqRoute, Boolean showPatientESig, Boolean showFamCancerHx, Boolean showHomeO2Use, Boolean showPONV, Boolean showAnestCompX, Boolean ShowCancerOnlyEndonly) Line 10361 + 0xe bytes    Basic
UserInterfaceLayer.dll!UserInterfaceLayer.Reports_RepDisp.PatRep(Short repnum) Line 2334 + 0x1f0 bytes  Basic
UserInterfaceLayer.dll!UserInterfaceLayer.Reports_RepDisp.PrintReport(Short repnum) Line 273 + 0x12 bytes   Basic
UserInterfaceLayer.dll!UserInterfaceLayer.Reports_RepDisp.Page_Load(Object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 33 + 0x13 bytes Basic
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(System.EventArgs e) Line 2254 + 0x5d bytes  C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() Line 2274  C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) Line 4624 + 0xe bytes   C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(bool includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, bool includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) Line 4296   C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() Line 4265 + 0xf bytes    C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(System.Web.HttpContext context) Line 4235 + 0x7 bytes  C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) Line 4225 + 0x9 bytes  C#
App_Web_ffa11ybr.dll!ASP.reports_repdisp_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x26 bytes   
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() Line 3451 + 0xa bytes    C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously) Line 2076 + 0x9 bytes    C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) Line 3783 + 0x20 bytes C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, object extraData) Line 1409 C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) Line 1695 + 0x12 bytes    C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) Line 2381 + 0xf bytes C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(System.IntPtr ecb, int iWRType) Line 169  C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIRuntime.System.Web.Hosting.IISAPIRuntime2.ProcessRequest(System.IntPtr ecb, int iWRType) Line 207 + 0x9 bytes    C#
```

Comment: Side-note: `Dim con As SqlConnection   If con Is Nothing Then` does not make much sense since it's always  `Nothing`. Also, you don't need to open/close the connection if you use `theDataAdapter.Fill(ds)`. Finally, don't use an empty catch and `Throw ex`, if you want to keep the original stack-trace use `Throw`.

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace? Can you also give the line number that is recurring?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: i'm afraid that he don't has it because of the `Throw Ex` instead of `Throw`.

Comment: Where and when do you call `RepSWSC`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Visual Studio will keep the stack trace in the debugger.

Comment: after create the command you should set the connection some how command.Connection = con

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I knew that con doesn't make much make sense, I was trying to write some funky test code to see if it resolves my problem, even after the change that you have mentioned didn't resolve the stackoverflow error.

Comment: @user3637303: Can you post the stack trace from visual studio?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, please find the stack trace.

Comment: What is there at line 17971 in BusinessAccessLayer.TestClass.RepSWSC()

Comment: theDataAdapter.Fill(ds)

Comment: @PatrickHofman and one more thing to let you know, the same code works in our test region and in prod but in dev it is breaking, the only difference I could see is in Dev there was a silverlight automatic update that happened on 07/24/2014 and from then on developers started complaining about this issue. I have removed silver light update as well but it didn't help.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yeah!! that doesn't solve this issue but something else that is going weird..:(

Comment: one more interesting thing that I am seeing, if I kill the w3p process then the same code is working with out any issues, but after two or three minutes it comes to the same issue. Do you guys tihnk if something related to IIS or memory issues?